# PHP Repeated function not showing - syntax error

Tags: javascript, php, frameworks

I want to make a category and subcategory selection - so when i press a category it will show next to it all subcategories.

I have made it work with html and js but now im making it in my site dinamically

thsi is what im using now

```
var categories_0 = [
    <?php while ( fanapom_has_categories() ) { ?>       


["<?php echo fanapom_category_id() ; ?>","<?php echo fanapom_category_name() ; ?>"], 
<?php } ?>
];




<?php while ( fanapom_has_categories() ) { ?>       
var categories_<?php echo fanapom_category_id() ; ?> = [<?php while ( fanapom_has_subcategories() ) { ?>["<?php echo fanapom_category_id() ; ?>","<?php echo fanapom_category_name() ; ?>"],<?php } ?>];

<?php } ?>
```

But  i used this code two times -but i see  it works only one time.

```
 <?php while ( fanapom_has_categories() ) { ?>
```

if i use this alone

```
 var categories_0 = [
    <?php while ( fanapom_has_categories() ) { ?>       


["<?php echo fanapom_category_id() ; ?>","<?php echo fanapom_category_name() ; ?>"], 
<?php } ?>
];
```

or this alone

```
<?php while ( fanapom_has_categories() ) { ?>       
var categories_<?php echo fanapom_category_id() ; ?> = [<?php while ( fanapom_has_subcategories() ) { ?>["<?php echo fanapom_category_id() ; ?>","<?php echo fanapom_category_name() ; ?>"],<?php } ?>];

<?php } ?>
```

I get correct output

but when i mix them both together i get only the output of the first one,

How can i make it work to give me the correct output?  I think i should not use this code two times

```
  <?php while ( fanapom_has_categories() ) { ?>
```

But im not sure how to mix the two together - Please help.

---

M O R E    I N F O

---

Here is what i want the output to look like

```
  var categories_0 = [
                            ["1", "maincategoryname"],
                            ["2", "maincategoryname"],
                            ["3", "maincategoryname"],
                            ["4", "maincategoryname"],
                            ["5", "maincategoryname"],
                            ["6", "maincategoryname"],
                            ["7", "maincategoryname"],
                            ["8", "maincategoryname"]
                        ];




                        var categories_1 = [
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"]
                        ];

                         var categories_2 = [
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"]
                        ];

 var categories_3 = [
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"]
                        ];

 var categories_4 = [
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"]
                        ];

 var categories_5 = [
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"]
                        ];

 var categories_6 = [
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"]
                        ];

 var categories_7 = [
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"]
                        ];

 var categories_8 = [
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"],
                            ["subcategoryid", "subcategoryname"]
                        ];
```

The 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  numbers are the main category id's

Comment: What is the source of the categories? A PHP array? I'm wondering why use a function and not a loop over the source data.

Comment: I think it will help to also post the working HTML/JS, here and/or in a JSFiddle.

Comment: Ok I will add to jsfiddle

Comment: Hi this is what im trying to acheive - http://jsfiddle.net/GTGuX/   in my example all osc are replaced with fanapom  (my function name)

Comment: You know, you'd do better to create the arrays all at once and then echo them using `json_encode`.  :P  Besides the fact that it's safer overall, your constant switching between PHP mode and JS mode murders readability.  (Especially since you use `<?php echo` rather than `<?=`.  :P )

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'm new to php and I need your help - can you shopw me an example of how i can make it work using arrays? and json_encode

Comment: Using PHP `json_encode` requires you to recode your JS functionality. However overall I think that'd be a more efficient and programmer-friendly way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to print the multidimensional javascript arrays in your example, assuming the data source is a similar multidimensional array in PHP:

```
$categories = array(
      "1" => array("one",   array("1" => "a", "2" => "b", "3" => "c"))
    , "2" => array("two",   array("4" => "d", "5" => "e", "6" => "f"))
    , "3" => array("three", array("7" => "g", "8" => "h", "9" => "i"))
);

$categories_js = 'var categories_0 = [';
$category_subs_js = '';
$delimiter1 = '';
$delimiter2 = '';
foreach ( $categories as $category_id => $category_info ) {
    $categories_js .= $delimiter1 . '["' . $category_id . '", "' . $category_info[0] . '"]';
    $delimiter1 = ', ';
    $category_subs_js .= 'var categories_' . $category_id . ' = [';
    foreach ( $category_info[1] as $subcat_id => $subcategory ) {
        $category_subs_js .= $delimiter2 . '["' . $subcat_id . '", "' . $subcategory . '"]';
        $delimiter2 = ', ';
    }
    $category_subs_js .= "];\n";
    $delimiter2 = '';
}
$categories_js .= "];\n";

echo $categories_js;
echo $category_subs_js;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `fanapom_has_` functions probably use up the iterator, which would prevent you from getting the list a second time.  (Reason #422835 why mutable global state is evil, BTW.  If you have a choice, i'd recommend you make your API less dependent on them.  Just because WordPress does it, doesn't mean it's a good idea.)

In order to fix that, you'd need to either reset the iterator somehow, or build the arrays for the main category and each subcategory at the same time (so you only need one pass through the list).

Frankly, you'd do better to quit farting around with building JSON by hand.  :P  PHP has a built-in function, `json_encode`, to do that.  All you have to do is build the arrays.  And you can do that in one pass.

Perhaps something like

```
<?php
$categories = [ [] ];
while (fanapom_has_categories()) {
    $id = fanapom_category_id();
    $categories[0][] = [ "$id", fanapom_category_name() ];
    $categories[$id] = [];
    while (fanapom_has_subcategories()) {
        # btw, this looks odd to me, using the same function to get info on the
        # category and subcategory, but using different functions to iterate through
        # the respective lists.
        $categories[$id][] = [ fanapom_category_id(), fanapom_category_name() ];
    }
}

foreach ($categories as $id => $subcategories) {
    echo "var categories_$id = ", json_encode($subcategories), ";\n";
}

?>
```

(Note: `[ item1, item2 ]` is PHP 5.4 spiff.  If you're stuck with an old and busted version of PHP, use `array(item1, item2)` instead.)